# LiveData Observer Recyclerview ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I want to create ChatScreen Like WhatsApp, to show list of users previously Chat. The Server Return only the ProfileIDs list. From those ProfileIDs the requirement is to fetch last message with profile from different APIs.

When RowItem is visible, I wrote observer in OnBindViewHolder to fetch last Message such as

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(chatsViewHolder: ChatsViewHolder, i: Int) {
...
chatsViewHolder.setLastMessage(
            chatsViewModel.getLastMessageWithProfile(
                chatsViewHolder.profileID,
                i
            )
        )

        chatsViewHolder.bindTo(chat, i)

...
}
```

and in ChatsViewHolder have added observer like this

```
fun setLastMessage(last_message: MutableLiveData<Resource<Any>>?) {
        this.last_message = last_message
    }

fun bindTo(conversation: ChatConversation?, position: Int) {
...
 last_message?.observe(lifecycleOwner!!) {
            when {
                it.status === Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    // update item.
                }

                it.status === Status.ERROR -> {}
            }
        }
...
}
```

is it correnct way to observe data in ViewHolder? or what should be done to fetch data to update Item when Item is visible (in this case loading last message when item is visible) using MVVM pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ListAdapter<Any, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffUtil)`
this link sample of an adapter that used `ListAdapter` and `DiffUtil` [Sample Code](https://github.com/mohsenghafarpour/cryptoCurrency/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ir/digipay/cryptocurrency/ui/currencies/CurrenciesAdapter.kt).
You should provide data in ViewModel and set value in your live data then observe your live data in fragment or activity and submit data to the adapter
When your data changes, you will notice it in `DiffUtil` and you can update your view status.
I hope this example helps you.